# Executing standard PowerShell cmdlets in remote session to Lync

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-remoting, lync, powershell-cmdlet

Having an odd issue over here. I'm able to start a remote session from my C# application to PowerShell in a Lync Server 2010 instance. I'm able to get all the Lync-specific cmdlets and execute them, but if I try to do something with a standard cmdlet — in my case "get-content" in order to convert a file to a byte array — it will not recognize the command.

Is there a way/need to load the standard PS set of cmdlets into that session? It feels like I'm missing something here...

Thanks in advance!

N

EDIT: Here's a code snippet of what I have going on...

```
PSCredential creds = new PSCredential(lyncUser, lyncPW);

        WSManConnectionInfo conn = new WSManConnectionInfo(new Uri(lyncURI), schema, creds);

        conn.AuthenticationMechanism = AuthenticationMechanism.Default;

        Runspace rs = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(conn);
        rs.Open();


        List<FileInfo> files = getWavFiles();

        foreach (var file in files)
        {

            Pipeline lyncCommands = rs.CreatePipeline();

            Command getContent = new Command("Get-Content");
            getContent.Parameters.Add(file.FullName);
            getContent.Parameters.Add("readcount", 0);
            getContent.Parameters.Add("encoding", "byte");
            lyncCommands.Commands.Add(getContent);

            Command importAnnouncement = new Command("import-csannouncementfile");
            importAnnouncement.Parameters.Add("parent", "applicationserver:myserver.mydomain.mycom");
            importAnnouncement.Parameters.Add("filename", file.Name);
            importAnnouncement.Parameters.Add("force");

            lyncCommands.Commands.Add(importAnnouncement);

            foreach (PSObject r in lyncCommands.Invoke())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(r.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
            }
        }
```

The "import-csannouncement" part will work just fine... it's "get-content" part that gets dicey...

Comment: Are you connecting to a special Lync remoting endpoint.  You can see what cmdlets are available by executing `icm -Session $lyncSession { $ExecutionContext.SessionState.InvokeCommand.GetCmdlets() }`

Comment: Thanks, Keith. Yeah, I'm connecting to the OCSpowershell URL. I can pipe in a get-command command on it, but all I see isLync cmdlets. So... where are the rest of them? I can't even run an add-pssnapin...

Comment: It could be that you are supposed to do an Import-Session which allows you to call the Lync cmdlets locally where you would have access to other cmdlets.  This is a common way to protect the server.  This quick start has more details: http://blogs.technet.com/b/csps/archive/2010/06/16/qsremoteaccess.aspx

Comment: Can't run import-session, either. Strangeness, indeed.

Comment: (Added a code snippet at the top to show where I'm at...)

Answer (score 0):

You can try re-configuring the LYNC server remote sessions for Full Language mode.

(Link is about configuring for Exchange servers, but I believe it's the same issue)

http://blog.mimecast.com/2011/08/get-full-control-over-your-exchange-remote-powershell-session/

Comment: Good suggestion! Alas, that didn't do the trick. I tried, and it didn't make a difference.

I initiated a remote PowerShell session into the Lync server, too, and it wouldn't let me do an import of the byte array because it was too large.

I think I've managed to circumvent the issue by installing the management shell in the host machine that will run the managed code, and that will take care of it. We shall see...

Comment: How big is the array? Remote session by default have a memory limit of 150MB, but you can increase that. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2010/05/03/configuring-wsman-limits.aspx